# Favicon won't load and throws error in console

Tags: javascript, html, angular

What work-arounds are available for this aside from updating the assets import in the angular.json file and adding an images folder in the assets directory?

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware that there are a number of posts around this. And I have solved the issue in my app. But it seems that you cannot access a favicon reliably from the src folder in an Angular app. In adding an images folder to the assets directory in the app, and accessing an icon or graphic from there...the app loads the app icon every time.

My current working solution:

- Add an **images** folder to the ./assets directory in your app. Place the image/icon in this folder and access it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Google favicon generator and make an icon. Name it favicon.ico and drop it in your webroot.

See if this helps.

Also here is a tutorial on favicon: https://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon